# How can I hide an element in an iframe under #document?

Tags: css, shadow-dom

Given the layout below, how can I hide `#header-precursor` if it's under `#link-preview` or `#linkPreviewIframe`?

[image]

Here is the basic layout in text form:

```
<p id="link-preview>
  <iframe id=linkPreviewIframe>
    #document
      <html>
        <head>..</head>
        <body>
          <div id="page">
            <div id="header-precursor">
              This is the one I want to hide
            </div>
          </div>
        </body>
      </html>
```

I tried `#link-preview #header-precursor { display: none;}` but it didn't work.  I don't know much about Shadow DOM but I think that's what #document indicates, so I tried this too with no luck: `#link-preview::shadow #header-precursor { display: none;}`

Comment: You'll have to inject CSS into this iframe; the document loaded there is treated as an entirely new page by a browser. [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe).

Comment: So if I can modify the CSS of the source of the iframe, what would it need to look like?

Comment: Just `#header-precursor { ... }`. It's basically a standalone stylesheet for a standalone page.

Comment: But I don't want to hide that if it's not loaded in an iframe.

Comment: Then you'll have to use JavaScript to augment some properties of that document dynamically.